# import httplib raises ValueError

Tags: python, exception, httplib

I have a python script that's been working great, but suddenly started throwing this when I try to start it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mdp3.py", line 5, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 73, in <module>
    from urlparse import urlsplit
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 321, in <module>
    for a in _hexdig for b in _hexdig)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 321, in <genexpr>
    for a in _hexdig for b in _hexdig)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '07'
```

Since it's happening before the script does anything, I'm concerned that maybe something broke in my python install.  But before I do anything drastic, I want to determine if I'm misinterpreting the exception.

Comment: You can create a virtualenv and try to run this script with fresh enviroment then you can determine is it a fault of your python install.

Comment: Hrm, even in Python 3 the call `int('07', 16)` doesn't fail. This is somewhat weird.

Comment: Hi Martijn. python --version returns 2.7.3?

Comment: and what does `int('07', 16)` entered in the Python prompt do?

Comment: Same exception: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '07'

Comment: Good suggestion adamr, however I can't install virtualenv because easy_install gives me the same error :(

Comment: That is very b0rken indeed. What does `int('7', 16)` do? I'm scanning through the C implementation (`Python/mystrtoul.c`, function `PyOS_strtol`).

Comment: Same exception: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '7'

Comment: We'll have to assume your `int()` implementation at the very least is very broken. If `int.__module__` prints `builtins`, that means your Python interpreter is broken. I cannot see any obvious ways for why this might be.

Comment: Thank @MartijnPieters, I'm going to switch machines to get things going again and update the post when I have time to do some forensics...